# Java Android App with Delphi REST Server

Tags: android, rest, delphi, server

I was wondering... I have a REST Server developed in Delphi. And I want to make an Andoid Application that uses the same data on that server. Can I do that? How? 
Do I only need the server address on my Andorid Application?

Comment: Rest clients in Delphi Android can be done the same way they are done in Delphi Windows. Google the tutorials. There are pre-made components you can put on the form in your Android project to configure to connect to the Rest server.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you will need some information about the server:

- List of URL endpoints
- Does it require any authentication?
- How does it return the data (JSON/XML/etc.)?

On the Android side of things, you will at a minimum need an HTTP Client ([OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) is very good). Also, don't to include `<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml file.